# Why can't I limit the number of rows in a Snowflake UDTF based on an input specifying that number?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, udtf

It appears I can't create a SQL UDTF where I hand in an argument N and then have a "LIMIT N" in the query in the body of the UDTF. I've read elsewhere on StackOverflow that this dynamic query generation doesn't work with UDTFs, but other things that I would have naively thought of as dynamic query generation do work, so I'm confused.

More specifics on what I tried:

I can create this UDTF in Snowflake:

```
CREATE FUNCTION top_n_prices(top_n INT)
  RETURNS TABLE (item VARCHAR, price NUMBER)
  AS
  $$
    SELECT MENU_ITEM_NAME, SALE_PRICE_USD 
    FROM FROSTBYTE_TASTY_BYTES.RAW_POS.MENU
    ORDER BY 2 DESC
    LIMIT 2
  $$
  ;
```

But I can't create the same UDTF where the LIMIT (above hard-coded as 2) changes based on the input. In other words, this doesn't work:

```
CREATE FUNCTION top_n_prices(top_n INT)
  RETURNS TABLE (item VARCHAR, price NUMBER)
  AS
  $$
    SELECT MENU_ITEM_NAME, SALE_PRICE_USD 
    FROM FROSTBYTE_TASTY_BYTES.RAW_POS.MENU
    ORDER BY 2 DESC
    LIMIT top_n
  $$
  ;
```

I've read a bit in other StackOverflow posts about how you can't write "dynamic queries" in UDTFs in Snowflake: [How to write dynamic queries in snowflake user defined functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62403809/how-to-write-dynamic-queries-in-snowflake-user-defined-functions)

Instead, I should use a stored procedure or find another solution.

But I'm still confused as to why -- I can do this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION menu_prices_above(price_floor INT)
  RETURNS TABLE (item VARCHAR, price NUMBER)
  AS
  $$
    SELECT MENU_ITEM_NAME, SALE_PRICE_USD 
    FROM FROSTBYTE_TASTY_BYTES.RAW_POS.MENU
    WHERE SALE_PRICE_USD > price_floor
    ORDER BY 2 DESC
  $$
  ;
```

Which feels fairly "dynamic" to me -- Like the other UDTF I wanted to make, the number of columns is pre-determined, but the number of rows is not. Depending on the price_floor, it could be a few, or many, just as with the earlier UDTF where LIMIT top_n should dictate the number of rows.

I'm not trying to argue that I'm "correct" here -- I just want to know how I'm thinking about this wrong, and whether it's true (as it seems to be) that a UDTF where you hand in an INT N and then try to LIMIT N is just not doable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same reason why this works:

```sql
select (select 1)
where 1 > (select 0)
limit 1;
```

And this doesn't:

```sql
select 1
where 1 > 0
limit (select 1);
```

This because some things in SQL can't be variables, but need to be constant. Hence we need to concatenate strings instead, like in [How to pass arguments for LIMIT and OFFSET in the snowflake sql stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78157848/how-to-pass-arguments-for-limit-and-offset-in-the-snowflake-sql-stored-procedure).

Comment: Thank you! That makes a lot of sense -- I hadn't realized that LIMIT (SELECT 1) would also fail. So it seems like if for some reason I really, really wanted to pull the first N rows using a UDTF (though I'm not sure why I would), in this particular case I could use a window function like ROW_NUMBER and combine that with ORDER BY, and then use a WHERE clause. That way I'm forcing limit-like behavior in through the WHERE

Comment: Scratch that -- My "trick" doesn't work:

SELECT MENU_ITEM_NAME, SALE_PRICE_USD, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SALE_PRICE_USD DESC) AS ROW_N
FROM FROSTBYTE_TASTY_BYTES.RAW_POS.MENU
WHERE ROW_N < 5;

Gives the following error: "Window function [ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MENU.SALE_PRICE_USD DESC NULLS FIRST)] appears outside of SELECT, QUALIFY, and ORDER BY clauses."